# Convert python dictionary into JavaScript json object and add to js file

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have a js file abc.js containing a JSON object as below:

```js
export default{
"Name": "James",
"Age": "21"
}
```

I have a python dictionary dict with the value:

```py
{"Country":"Italy"}
```

How can I append dict to abc.js such that it becomes:

```js
export default{

"Name": "James",
"Age": "21",
"Country":"Italy"
}
```

I tried the below approach:

```py
with open("abc.js", "w") as file:
    json.dump(dict, file)
```

I'm aware that this will replace the whole file but is there any way to append while also keeping the export default{} ?

Comment: You need to read the file, parse the JSON into a dictionary, add the country to the dictionary, convert that to JSON, then write that back to the file.

Comment: Note also that the file isn't JSON, it's JavaScript. You need to remove `export default` when reading, and add it back when writing.

Comment: How can I add the export default back to the file while writing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `export default` when reading the file, and add it back when writing.

```py
with open("abc.js") as f:
    contents = f.read()

contents = contents.replace('export default', '')
data = json.loads(contents)
data['Country'] = 'Italy'
new_contents = 'export default' + json.dumps(data)

with open("abc.js", "w") as f:
    f.write(new_contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also extract JSON data from your js file, merge it with your Python dictionary, and write it back to the file.

```
import json
with open("abc.js","r") as file:
    contents = file.read()
json_object = json.loads(contents[contents.index("{"):])
countries = {"Country":"Italy"}

merged_object = {**json_object, **countries}

with open("abc.js","w") as file:
    file.write("export default " + json.dumps(merged_object, indent = 4))
```